# How does color temperature influence headlight performance?

Tags: headlight, led

When driving at night with an LED spot light, generally them come with a bright white, 3 watt LEDs. Traditionally spotlights have been more of a warm white thanks to being halogen bulbs. If you bothered to replace the LEDs to warm white, would they be better suited to night time driving vs bright white?

Answer (score 4):

The color of light, expressed in degrees Kelvins (K). The sun is about 5800 K. This is called a "temperature," because the hotter a flame or a lamp filament  gets, the more it changes from a warm yellow glow to white.

The lower the color temperature such as the common incandescent/tungsten bulb, the warmer, softer and more yellow the light. The higher the K number, the cooler, whiter and bluer the light. The color temperature affects  the way we humans perceive color. Whether or not it is better is purely subjective. Since the color temperature of LED lights (bright white) is comparable to daylight in spectra it would probably be easier on the eyes under ideal conditions. It might annoy oncoming traffic if not properly aimed.

On the other hand in foggy or inclement conditions the warmer lights would work better the eye is more sensitive to yellow and is subject to less light scatter as a more bluer light. This is one reason why fog lights are yellow.